# Port-forwarded connection (adb) being reset

Tags: adb

I'm connected to an Android phone (being hosted on OpenSTF) via `adb` and have run

```
$ adb reverse tcp:34567 tcp:34567
```

`adb reverse --list` confirms that the command was successful.  I've also got an HTTP server listening on my computer at `127.0.0.1:34567`.  I've compiled a simple C program which creates a socket connection to `127.0.0.1:34567`, sends a `GET` request, and then calls `read` on the socket.

When I run the program on the phone, it successfully connects and I'm able to send my request.  However, `read` fails with

> Connection reset by peer

Running Wireshark on my computer shows no TCP packets on port 34567 (I'm listening on the `any` "interface").

Am I missing something obvious?  It's strange that the connection succeeds but that no packets reach my computer.

I don't have the issue if I connect a phone to my computer directly (i.e., via USB).

Comment: Is the PC running Windows? Not sure if localhost is covered by the "any" interface. AFAIR localhost is very special on Windows and Wireshark wasn't able to capture it at all, I think that changed with the latest major version of WinPcap so if you want to capture localhost make sure to use the latest versions of Wireshark and WinPcap and select the localhost interface for capturing. On Android side start with a standard program like telnet (e.g. in a Termux shell) instead your custom app.

Comment: No, this is a Linux PC.